# How can I isolate my viewer with a globalID?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I want to isolate a layer but not with node. I want use the globalId of my layer. It is possible?
I use this function myViewer.isolate();
Thanks =D

Comment: Please share more details like piece of code, you tried to help you quickly

Comment: I may not understand correctly on your question. Do you mean isolating the node of a layer,  while you do not know how to get toe layer id? Actually a layer is also a node. you could filter out which is layer and get id, or when you get a geometry node, try to find its parent nodes